# How to decrease LPC in WordPress site mobile

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know the reason of this element I attached the screenshot of auditing of side. I use almost every optimiser plugin but I didn't get the result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first check where the problem is/ which part of your website is not properly configured on [Gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/).

From the generated report you'll most likely have to minify your javascript and css as well as resize photos. Use plugins like [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) to minify js and css. Compress images with [any of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=comprr%20ess%20jpg&rlz=1C1GCEA_enKE983KE983&oq=comprr%20ess%20jpg&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13l9.5283j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Finally cache your website using [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)

Of there are more plugins you can substitute for the ones I provide, these are just free to use.

Comment: Okay I try do by your suggestion

Comment: I thing more I have to ask by using website auditing tools we can not find the root cause of problem

Comment: The audit generates a report with recommendations on what you need to do. to improve the rating.